# How to design this site menu style in WPF

Tags: c#, css, wpf, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to implement www.devexpress.com menu.
But I do not know what to do to implement the unfolding details below.

this is my source file.
[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2twYdJfAGHHYXUtU0I4YVdRak0)

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MenuTest02"
    xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" x:Class="MenuTest02.MainWindow"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="579.8" Width="1600" WindowState="Maximized">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="styleTopMenu" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Microsoft JhengHei"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            x:Name="mnuContent" Margin="0"/>
                        <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" BorderBrush="Gray" 
                            BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                            Height="30"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="1"/>
                        <!--
                        <Polyline Name="mnuTriangle" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Visibility="Visible"
                                  Points="0,10 10,0 20,10 0,10" Fill="#FF313131"/> -->
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">                                
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="BlueViolet"/>
                            <!-- <Setter TargetName="grdProductsSubmenu" Property="Visibility" Value="True"/> -->
                        </Trigger>                            
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <!-- <GridLength x:Key="GridLength1">1195</GridLength> -->
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="grdMainDisplay" Width="1195" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <!-- Top border -->
    <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Background="#FF4A4A4A" Width="Auto" Height="26"/>
    <!-- bottom Line in menu -->
    <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Background="Transparent" Width="Auto" Height="1" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,66,0,0"/>

    <!-- Top Menu -->
    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Height="66" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="images\logo.png" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="66"/>

        <!--
        <Border Grid.Column="2" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="30"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="1"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" FontSize="18" Text="   Products   " />
        -->
        <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="   Products   " Style="{StaticResource styleTopMenu}"/>
        <Button Grid.Column="3" Content="   Free Trials &amp; Demos   " Style="{StaticResource styleTopMenu}"/>
        <Button Grid.Column="4" Content="   Buy   " Style="{StaticResource styleTopMenu}"/>
        <Button Grid.Column="5" Content="   Support   " Style="{StaticResource styleTopMenu}"/>
        <Button Grid.Column="6" Content="   My Account   " Style="{StaticResource styleTopMenu}"/>
        <Button Grid.Column="7" Content="   About Us   " Style="{StaticResource styleTopMenu}"/>

        <Image Grid.Column="8" Source="images\cart_blogs_search.jpg" Margin="30,0,0,0" Height="54" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,56,0,0" Height="10" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Polyline x:Name="triProducts" Margin="320,0,0,0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Points="0,10 10,0 20,10 0,10" Fill="#FF313131" Visibility="Hidden"/>
        <Polyline Name="triFreeTrials" Margin="480,0,0,0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Points="0,10 10,0 20,10 0,10" Fill="#FF313131" Visibility="Hidden"/>
        <Polyline Name="triBuy" Margin="620,0,0,0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Points="0,10 10,0 20,10 0,10" Fill="#FF313131" Visibility="Hidden"/>
        <Polyline Name="triSupport" Margin="705,0,0,0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Points="0,10 10,0 20,10 0,10" Fill="#FF313131" Visibility="Hidden"/>
        <Polyline Name="triMyAccount" Margin="830,0,0,0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Points="0,10 10,0 20,10 0,10" Fill="#FF313131" Visibility="Hidden"/>
        <Polyline Name="triAboutUs" Margin="950,0,0,0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Points="0,10 10,0 20,10 0,10" Fill="#FF313131" Visibility="Hidden"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="0,66,0,0" Height="Auto" Visibility="Hidden"
        VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FF313131" x:Name="grdProductsSubmenu" Panel.ZIndex="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=grdMainDisplay, Path=Width}"/>                
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <Grid Visibility="Visible">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock Text="Suites" FontSize="18" Foreground="DarkGray"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="BEST VALUE" Margin="0,10,0,10" FontSize="14" Foreground="Orange"/>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Fill="#FFF88E1D" Height="26" Width="26" RadiusX="3" RadiusY="3"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Margin="0" Text="Universal" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,20,0,15" Foreground="DarkGray" FontSize="11" TextWrapping="Wrap"><Run Text="(includes all DevExpress.Netl"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="products in one integrated suite)"/></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Fill="#FF406EA4" Height="26" Width="26" RadiusX="3" RadiusY="3"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,0,0,0" Text="Dxperience" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,20,0,0" Foreground="DarkGray" FontSize="11" TextWrapping="Wrap"><Run Text="(includes all DevExpress.Netl"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="Controls along with CodeRush)"/></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>

                    <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,50,0,0"
                            Fill="#FF4C4C4C" Height="50" Width="230" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2"/>
                    <TextBlock Margin="0,-50,0,0" FontSize="14"
                            Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <Run Text="Compare Features"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="and Pricing"/>
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>

                <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="4" Height="Auto" Width="20" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1,0,0,0" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>


                <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock Text=".NET Products" FontSize="18" Foreground="DarkGray"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="INDIVIDUAL PLATFORMS" Margin="0,10,0,0" FontSize="14" Foreground="Orange"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="WinForms"  FontSize="14" Foreground="White"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="ASP.NET"  FontSize="14" Foreground="White"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="MVC"  FontSize="14" Foreground="White"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="WPF"  FontSize="14" Foreground="White"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Windows 10 Apps"  FontSize="14" Foreground="White"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="CROSS-PLATFORM" Margin="0,10,0,0"  FontSize="14" Foreground="Orange"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Reporting"  FontSize="14" Foreground="White"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Document Automatoin"  FontSize="14" Foreground="White"/>
                </StackPanel>

                <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="220,24,0,0">
                    <TextBlock Text="ENTERPRISE TOOLS" Margin="0,10,0,0"  FontSize="14" Foreground="Orange"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Report Server"  FontSize="14" Foreground="White"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Analytics Dashboard"  FontSize="14" Foreground="White"/>

                    <TextBlock Text="FRAMEWORKS" Margin="0,10,0,0"  FontSize="14" Foreground="Orange"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="eXpressApp Framework"  FontSize="14" Foreground="White"/>

                    <TextBlock Text="CODE-DEBUG-REFACTOR" Margin="0,10,0,0"  FontSize="14" Foreground="Orange"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="CodeRush for Visual Studio"  FontSize="14" Foreground="White"/>
                </StackPanel>

                <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Grid.RowSpan="4" Height="Auto" Width="20" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1,0,0,0" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>

                <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Text="HTML JS Products"  FontSize="18" Foreground="DarkGray"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="HYBRID APPS" Margin="0,10,0,0"  FontSize="14" Foreground="Orange"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="DevExtreme Moboile"  FontSize="14" Foreground="White"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="DevExtreme Web"  FontSize="14" Foreground="White"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Text="Xamarin.Forms"  FontSize="18" Foreground="DarkGray"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="UI CONTROLS" Margin="0,10,0,0"  FontSize="14" Foreground="Orange"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Free Data Grid"  FontSize="14" Foreground="White"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Text="iOS"  FontSize="18" Foreground="DarkGray"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="NATIVE" Margin="0,10,0,0"  FontSize="14" Foreground="Orange"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="DataExplorer"  FontSize="14" Foreground="White"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Text="Testing Tools"  FontSize="18" Foreground="DarkGray"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="WEB TESTING" Margin="0,10,0,0"  FontSize="14" Foreground="Orange"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="TestCafe"  FontSize="14" Foreground="White"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Text="Delphi &amp; C++Builder Products"  FontSize="18" Foreground="DarkGray"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="DELPHI &amp; C++BUILDER" Margin="0,10,0,0"  FontSize="14" Foreground="Orange"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="VCL"  FontSize="14" Foreground="White"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>

            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>

    <!-- Main Display -->
    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Height="Auto" Margin="0,66,0,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=grdMainDisplay, Path=Width}"/>                
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Run Text="(includes all DevExpress.Netl"/>
            <LineBreak/>
            <Run Text="Controls along with CodeRush)"/>
            <LineBreak/>
            <Run Text="Some Text..."/>
        </TextBlock>
        <Path Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Data="M50.0000011012083,0.5L99.5000021617096,99.5L0.00000040707015,99.5z" Stroke="Black"
            StrokeThickness="4" Fill="Yellow"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: you should paste your code here instead of linking to a random file. Are you having a specific problem? Or just generally looking for pointers?

Answer (score 1):

you can set a grid with 4 columsn and 2 rows.

In each of the upper cells you place one of the section names

In the bottom row you place one panel with the details, set its property `Grid.ColumnSpan = 4 Grid.Column = 0 grid.row = 1` so it spreads through the whole section. (I think this part is pretty ok in your code) and `visibility=visible opacity=1`

Then you hook to the on mouse enter for each of the upper elements and when entering, you set the opacity of all the lower panels to 0, but the desired one to 1.

This will show the desired panel with no animation. When you have it working, to achieve the animation you need to use DoubleAnimation and animate the opacity property of the other to zero instead of just setting it.

Please let us know if you find particular problems in your way